# JavaScript string split by Regex results sub-strings include empty slices

Tags: javascript, split

I've the following string splitting JavaScript code:

```
var formula = "(field1 + field2) * (field5 % field2) / field3";
console.log(formula.split(/[+(-)% *\/]/));
```

And the result is out of expectation:

```
["", "field1", "", "", "field2", "", "", "", "", "field5", "", "", "field2", "", "", "", "field3"]
```

What the desired result would be:

```
["field1", "field2", "field5", "field2", "field3"]
```

I'm using Google Chrome 11 official release as the testing browser, please kindly advise what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you!

William

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of splitting on `/[+(-)% *\/]/` split on more than one: `/[+(-)% *\/]+/`.  You still might get empty matches at the start and end.  To solve that problem you can use a similar regex with replace:

```
formula.replace(/^[+(-)% *\/]+|[+(-)% *\/]+$/g, "").split(/[+(-)% *\/]+/)
```

So

```
var formula = "(field1 + field2) * (field5 % field2) / field3";
console.log(formula.replace(/^[+(-)% *\/]+|[+(-)% *\/]+$/g, "").split(/[+(-)% *\/]+/));
```

yields

```
field1,field2,field5,field2,field3
```

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting at each of those characters. If you split on groups of them, you'll get your desired result.

```
console.log(formula.split(/[+(-)% *\/]+/));
```

There's just one snag: you will have to manually strip off those characters from the beginning and the end of the string (or pop off an empty string at the start/end) - it's not something you'll be able to handle by `split` alone.